# Eliminate [temporary] permanently?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Many of the questions with the [temporary](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/temporary) tag deal with temp variables, folders or files, but otherwise, this is a motley collection of stuff.  Does this tag add value for any use?

Answer (score 1):

No, it should be just cleared out